# Parse issue expected expression

Tags: objective-c, xctest, expected-exception

I'm stumped by this error. 
`XCTAssertNotNil` autocompleted alright and the code seems trivial. 
"Parse issue" seems so strange, and there are 3 of them.

I've tried showing invisibles to find any weird spaces and stuff, but could find nothing.

I'm using Specta/Xpecta/OCMock on my other tests. Using Cocoapods

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface SPRecipientDataViewModelTests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation SPRecipientDataViewModelTests

- (void)testHelloNotNil {
    XCTAssertNotNil(@"hello", @"hello is nil");
}
```

[image: Expected expression]

[image: parse issue expected expression]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem here was Specta. It looks like I was using an old version of it. Updating to the latest Specta fixed this problem. Looks like there was some conflict with XCTest